# How to use an image on the left in a cell of UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I want to use radio button images in each cell of my TableView. This images should be aligned to the left so that it would give an impression of selecting a single from multiple rows.

Please provide me with links, tutorials or code snippets.

Thanks,

Comment: It worked..... but if you can tell me how to select a particular cell here. That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to create custom cell.
and change image of whole cell including radiobutton image when it is selected..

Comment: just download any custome cell example and set imageview like checkbutton with frame CGRectmake (2,5,30,30). and set radio button images in it .